# Error Message "Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted" when starting windowsservice

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

We use a windowsservice which initializes and starts quartz jobs.
Everything works fine on the application servers so when I start the service, the jobs and triggers get scheduled and execute at the exact start time.

I now tried to install the windows service locally on my pc to test something but when I start it and quartz tries to initialize, the following error message appears in our log files:

> only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

The code where the error occurs is the following:

```
var properties = SetupDefaultProperties();
properties["quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames"] = "~/quartz_jobs.xml";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.port"] = "555";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName"] = "QuartzScheduler";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType"] = "tcp";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName"] = "httpQuartz";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.rejectRemoteRequests"] = "true";

var sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);

return sf.GetScheduler();
```

Have you experienced something like this before and know how to fix it?

Is something blocking port 555?

Can I just use another port or does it have to be port 555 (UDC/TCP)

Comment: That error happens when there's already a socket bound to the port you are trying to use. What happens if you change the port #? I don't know anything about Quartz, never mind why it would need a network socket (I guess some kind of remoting, based on the config text you posted). Port 555 is official assigned (by IANA) for something called "dsf" (which I've never heard of), but it seems that many malware programs also use it. Maybe you just need to run a virus checker, or reformat/reinstall your drive/OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port in your config file (or in your case, in your properties) without any issues. Make sure you update your firewall rules to allow access to it though.